# Google App Engine /form url error

Tags: google-app-engine

I've got a very peculiar error with App Engine. I have noticed that when I try to open myapp.appspot.com/form url it gives me a strange 404 error.

> Error: Not Found
>   The requested URL /form was not found on this server.

This happens to any app. For example: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/form

If there are no app instances running, and I try to open any invalid url, app engine gives me 404 error but anyway it start a new instance and writes this http request to log. But when I try to open myapp.appspot.com/form it doesn't even start an instance nor it writes the request to log.

That seems very strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/form` is a reserverd URL - see the docs  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Reserved_URLs